# HTML/CSS Put a DIV on top of other with z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I've 3 main layers in my website:

**1)** Main view with elements inside (#views in jsbin) - BOTTOM LAYER
**2)** Overlay (with white background opacity .8 #overlay in jsbin) - MIDDLE LAYER
**3)** Context menu (#contextmenu in jsbin) - TOP LAYER

When I show the context menu, the 3 layers are displayed correctly -> main view is "hidden" by the transparent overlay and the context menu is on the top.

Now my problem is that I want to pop out an element inside the main view. I want to display this element (#card1 in jsbin) between the context menu and the overlay...but I'm not able to achieve this. Is it possible?

Here is my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/gaxadaci/7/edit

Thanks for your help.
Kind regards,
Bastien

Comment: Can you make your jsbin editable?

Comment: why not use javascript if your change is made on a user interaction and not on page load ?

Comment: It's hard to make out why the overlay is even needed. With this example, you could easily put css `opacity`to each box and then change each opacity individually when hovered over. --- Although I might be reading into it too much, because you only say you want to "pop out", but you don't say when or how.

Comment: no problem, I can use javascript... but how to do it??

Comment: here is the editable jsbin: http://jsbin.com/gaxadaci/7/edit

Comment: @Joonas > yes, but I need the overlay. I can not put opacity on every element. My jsbin is very simplified compared to my application that has many other elements that should be "hidden" by the overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the card; `z-index` is not applied to `static` elements.

It is important to note that if any parent of your "element to pop out" has its own `z-index` defined, then this method *will not work* (and there'll be *no* way to "pop it out") because that parent defines the stacking context for its children.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add "position: relative" to your card div

```
#card1 {
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
    }
```

JSbin http://jsbin.com/gaxadaci/13/